# Find open and closed status using mysql useing timezone php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timezone

All code is working but i need help in Timezone..
How to use Timezone In this Query ?

```
public function res_openandclose($res_id,$time_open,$time_close)
    {
        $db=getDB();
        $timezone = '<span class="timezone"></span>';
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  fooddelivery_restaurant  WHERE id=:res_id AND CURTIME() >= :open_time and CURTIME() <= :close_time ");
        $stmt->bindParam("res_id", $res_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam("open_time", $time_open, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam("close_time", $time_close, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($count)
        {
            return "open";
        }
        else
        {
            return "closed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Please specify _how_ you wanna use _what_ timezone (the user's? The server's? The restaurant's? Alltogether?).

Comment: We need some additional information to be able to help you, where does <span class="timezone"></span> come from? Is it dynamically set? If so you will need to use jQuery+AJAX to parse the value to PHP.

Comment: @jeff this Users Time

Comment: @JulianKoster <span class="timezone"></span> come from java script users current timezone

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take values from DOM elements which are dynamically set by Javascript. You will need to use a combination of jQuery + AJAX + PHP.

I'll make a few assumptions:

1. Your PHP file is called "process.php"
2. Your HTML document (in which `<span class="timezone"></span>` is contained) is called form.php
3. Even though I'm not a fan of including jQuery/Javascript in form.php, for ease of this answer I'll include it anyway.
4. The timezone set by Javascript follows the regular format found at: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

In this case please try the following:

**STEP ONE:**

If not already included, include jQuery in the header of form.php. You can copy/paste this in the header of form.php:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**STEP TWO**

Include the following in the BODY of your document, but right before the `</body>` closing tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
        "use strict";
        var TimeZone = ($(".timezone").html());

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {Purpose : "CallFunction", Function: "res_openandclose", TimeZone : TimeZone},
            success: function (response) 
                {
                      alert(response); //will alert either "open" or "closed"
                }
        });
    });//end function
</script>
```

**STEP THREE**

Modify your process.php to reflect the following

```
//Receive Parameters from AJAX for Function Calls
if(isset($_POST["Purpose"]) && $_POST["Purpose"] === "CallFunction") {

    if(isset($_POST["Function"]) && $_POST["Function"] === "res_openandclose") {
        res_openandclose($res_id,$time_open,$time_close);
    }//end if

}//end if

    public function res_openandclose($res_id,$time_open,$time_close)
        {
if(isset($_POST["TimeZone"]) {
$timezone = $_POST["TimeZone"];
            $db=getDB();
            date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  fooddelivery_restaurant  WHERE id=:res_id AND CURTIME() >= :open_time and CURTIME() <= :close_time ");
            $stmt->bindParam("res_id", $res_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("open_time", $time_open, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("close_time", $time_close, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            if($count)
            {
                return "open";
            }
            else
            {
                return "closed";
            }
        }
```

Save all files and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
public function res_openandclose($res_id,$time_open,$time_close, $time_zone)
{
    $db = getDB();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  fooddelivery_restaurant  WHERE id=:res_id AND CURTIME() >= :open_time and CURTIME() <= :close_time and timezone = :time_zone");

    $stmt->bindParam("res_id", $res_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam("open_time", $time_open, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam("close_time", $time_close, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam("time_zone", $time_zone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($count){
        return "open";
    }
    else{
        return "closed";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want static timezone

Comment: Pass the $time_zone in function parameter like this 
res_openandclose($res_id,$time_open,$time_close, $time_zone) instead of defining it in function

Comment: Check it now. Added $time_zone as parameter to function